# Why is URL rewriting not working in tomcat 8 when I proxy pass URLs using nginx

Tags: tomcat, nginx, url-rewriting

[Tomcat 8 URL rewrite](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html) is not working when requests are proxy passed from nginx server.  But the same url-rewrite is working when requests are directly served from tomcat server.

I am having nginx server listening to 80 port and tomcat server listening to 9080 port.

nginx proxy-pass configuration

```
http 
{
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server 
    {
        listen       80;
        location /app/ 
        {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9080/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        }
    }
}
```

tomcat rewrite.config file

```
RewriteRule ^app/xyz    /app/abc        [L]
```

When I try to access the url http://server-name/app/xyz, the URL rewriting is not working. But when accessed directly via tomcat listening port(server-name:9080/app/xyz) it is working.

EDIT

Previously I had the URL rewriting configured in nginx.

nginx url rewrite configuration

```
location /app/ 
{
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9080/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        include /dev_resource/nginx/rewrite.conf;
}
```

nginx rewrite.conf

```
rewrite ^/app/xyz       /app/abc        break;
```

When I try to access the url `http://server-name/app/xyz`, the url rewriting is working. The request is not being forwarded to  `http://server-name/xyz`.

But when url rewriting is configured with tomcat 8, the url `http://server-name/app/xyz` is being forwarded to `http://server-name/xyz`.

Comment: I notice that `http://server-name/app/xyz` is being forwarded to `http://server-name:9080/xyz`. Is that the problem?

Comment: Yeah that was the problem. But what is the reason for the behaviour mentioned in my edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`proxy_pass` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) may or may mot rewrite the URI, depending on its parameter and the surrounding `location` directive.

This `location` and `proxy_pass` combination will map URIs like `/app/xxx` to `/xxx` upstream:

```
location /app/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9080/;
}
```

In order to pass URIs upstream transparently, remove the URI element from the `proxy_pass` directive (including the `/`):

```
location /app/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9080;
}
```

So, in answer to your first question (before the EDIT), the reason *Tomcat* did not rewrite the URI was because there were no URIs being received that matched the rule. That is, no URIs that started with `/app/` because `proxy_pass` had already removed that prefix.

In answer to your second question (after the EDIT), the `nginx` rewrite sees the URI before it is changed by `proxy_pass`. So the URI `/app/xyz` is mapped to `/app/abc` by the `rewrite` directive, then mapped to `/abc` by the `proxy_pass` directive before being sent upstream. So, *Tomcat* receives `/abc`.

In conclusion, if *Tomcat* should be seeing URIs beginning with `/app/`, then you need to fix the `proxy_pass` directive (as shown above), and then rewrite will work the same in both the front-end and the back-end.

However, if *Tomcat* should be seeing URIs with the `/app` prefix removed, then any rewrite rules in *Tomcat* should **not** include the `/app` prefix in the match regex.